# glossaries: including an entry without page location

Tags: page-numbering, glossaries

In the `glossaries` package, `\glssee{label}{aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd}` will cross-reference entries, but it doesn't include the referenced entry if it is not otherwise included in the glossary. (e.g. there will be missing links).

The package provides the `\glsadd` command to include a glossary entry without generating a link or other text on the page, so one could add the missing entries like so

```
\glsadd{entry1}\glsadd{entry2}\glsadd{entry3}
\printglossaries
```

But this will add the page number to the numberlist (the page before the glossary). I suppose `\glsadd` was primarily meant for referencing page ranges with its optional argument.

There is the `nonumberlist` package option, but is it really necessary to drop an entire feature just to do away with a few irrelevant page numbers?

**For example, can `\glsadd` be redefined in a way that doesn't add the page number to the numberlist?**

(It's very predictable, so if one knows that page 192 is not necessary, one could manually remove the extra `\setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{192}\delimN` strings from the `.gls` file when adding the final polish to the document, but I wonder if that hack can be avoided.)

Comment: If you have multiple lists nomenclature, glossaries, acronyms etc and you want to have page numbers removed for some of them, just modify the style of the list or create a new one that doesn't uses the page variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a new command `\gslgobblenumber` that will gobble its argument, and redefine `\glsadd` so that it will write `\glsgobblenumber` instead of `\glsnumberformat` into the `.glo` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\glsgobblenumber}[1]{}
% \renewcommand*{\glsgobblenumber}[1]{#1}% uncomment for testing

\renewcommand*{\glsadd}[2][]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
%     \def\@glsnumberformat{glsnumberformat}% DELETED
    \def\@glsnumberformat{glsgobblenumber}% NEW
    \edef\@gls@counter{\csname glo@#2@counter\endcsname}%
    \setkeys{glossadd}{#1}%
    \@gls@saveentrycounter
    \@do@wrglossary{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{oesophagus}{name=\oe sophagus,
description={canal from mouth to stomach}}
\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,
description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\begin{document}

Some text about \gls{oesophagus}.

\glsadd{electrolyte}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution is to specify the `nonumberlist` option for the glossary entries that are only cross-referenced:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{first}{name={First}, description={First Term}, nonumberlist}
\glsadd{first}

\newglossaryentry{second}{name={Second}, description={Second Term}, see=first}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\gls{second}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there is a nice way to do this in `glossaries-extra`: `\glsadd[noindex=true]{first}`.