# Glossaries: suppress pages when using glsaddall

Tags: glossaries

I would like to generate an index of notation using the `glossaries`-package such that certain page numbers are suppressed.

It is easy to define some standard notation and include it in the index using `\glsaddall`.
But this adds the page numbers to the index, which is what I want to avoid.

Adding `nonumberlist` to the definition of an entry suppresses the page number. (`nonumberlist` also exists as package option, but not as option to `\glsaddall`.) But this has to be done for each entry and would also suppress future references.

Here is my question: **How can I suppress all page numbers generated by `\glsaddall`?**  In other words: `\glsaddall` ensures that all notation not referenced by `\gls` appears in the index, but without having a page number. All entries generated by `\gls` add page numbers.

Here is a good example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand*{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand*{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

% glossaries-user.pdf (v3.03):
% If you use hyperref and glossaries, you must load hyperref first.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
  style=long3colheader,
  hyperfirst=false
  ]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{integers}{name=\ensuremath{\Z},
  description={the ring of integers}, sort=!}
\newglossaryentry{rationals}{name=\ensuremath{\Q},
  description={the field of rational numbers}, sort=!, nonumberlist}

\newglossaryentry{vector-space}{name=\ensuremath{V},
  description={a vector space}, sort=V}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

A vector space \gls{vector-space} \ldots

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The output is the following. The pages for Z and Q should not appear. (The page for Q is suppressed manually.)

[image: Output]

(This question is related but not equal to [glossaries: including an entry without page location](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16062/17127).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an approach that works with only a minor restriction: Instead of issuing `\gladdall` in the beginning, we issue a `\glsaddallunused` right before we do `\printglossaries`. This new command `\glsaddallunused` will write all entries that have not been used up to this point to the glossaries, with suppressed page numbers. For the suppression we will use lockstep's answer that you linked to.

If we were to write all entries with `\glsaddall` to the auxiliary glossary file, we would have a hard time to teach `makeindex` which page numbers to suppress, and how to sort and compress that correctly. In my approach, we only have entries with all page numbers shown (those explicitly referenced), and entries with completely suppressed page list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand*{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand*{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

\usepackage{lipsum} % to have some dummy text, and therefore larger page numbers
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[
  style=long3colheader,
  hyperfirst=false
  ]{glossaries}

\newcommand*{\glsgobblenumber}[1]{}
% \renewcommand*{\glsgobblenumber}[1]{#1}% uncomment for testing

\makeatletter
%% lockstep's code
\newcommand*{\glsaddnp}[2][]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
%     \def\@glsnumberformat{glsnumberformat}% DELETED
    \def\@glsnumberformat{glsgobblenumber}% NEW
    \edef\@gls@counter{\csname glo@#2@counter\endcsname}%
    \setkeys{glossadd}{#1}%
    \@gls@saveentrycounter
    \@do@wrglossary{#2}%
  }%
}
%% new code; modified \glsaddall
\newcommand{\glsaddallunused}[1][]{%
  \edef\@glo@type{\@glo@types}%
  \setkeys{glossadd}{#1}%
  \forallglsentries[\@glo@type]{\@glo@entry}{%
    \ifglsused{\@glo@entry}{}{%
     \glsaddnp[#1]{\@glo@entry}}}%
}
\makeatother


\newglossaryentry{integers}{name=\ensuremath{\Z},
  description={the ring of integers}, sort=Z}

\newglossaryentry{rationals}{name=\ensuremath{\Q},
  description={the field of rational numbers}, sort=Q, nonumberlist}

\newglossaryentry{vector-space}{name=\ensuremath{V},
  description={a vector space}, sort=V}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
A vector space \gls{vector-space} \ldots
\lipsum[1-10]

\glsaddallunused
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: More complicated than I hoped, but a perfect answer. `\glsaddallunused` is absolutely acceptable. Thank you!

Comment: @Thomas You are welcome. It is indeed not so simple, but this is due to the limitations of `makeindex`. And if you put all this code into its own package, say `myglos.sty`, and load that with `\usepackage{myglos}`, your main file will look clean again ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative that doesn't use internal commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand*{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand*{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
  style=long3colheader,
  hyperfirst=false
  ]{glossaries}

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}

\newglossaryentry{integers}{name=\ensuremath{\Z},
  description={the ring of integers}, sort=!}
\newglossaryentry{rationals}{name=\ensuremath{\Q},
  description={the field of rational numbers}, sort=!, nonumberlist}

\newglossaryentry{vector-space}{name=\ensuremath{V},
  description={a vector space}, sort=V}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

A vector space \gls{vector-space} \ldots

\printglossaries


\forallglsentries{\thislabel}%
{%
  \ifglsused{\thislabel}{}{\glsadd[format=ignore]{\thislabel}}%
}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of glossary]

Comment: I want it to be in this form: http://imgur.com/j3bVshQ
Also in the example with the glossaries the text appears before the glossary? Shoudln't it be the other way around?

Comment: @Bob1990 It depends entirely on the document whether the glossary goes at the front or back. Just move `\printglossaries` (or `\printglossary`) to where you want it to appear. There are 100 different predefined glossary styles, which can all be adjusted. Have a look at the [glossaries styles gallery](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/) to see which best suits your requirement.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to change the name from Glossary to Acronyms?

Comment: @Bob1990 `\printglossary[title=Acronyms]` instead of `\printglossaries` or add package option `acronyms`.

Answer (score 2):

The command `\glsaddallunused` suggested by @mafp has been added to `glossaries` package.

So the example can be reduced to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand*{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand*{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

\usepackage{lipsum} % to have some dummy text, and therefore larger page numbers
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[
  style=long3colheader,
  hyperfirst=false
  ]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{integers}{name=\ensuremath{\Z},
  description={the ring of integers}, sort=Z}

\newglossaryentry{rationals}{name=\ensuremath{\Q},
  description={the field of rational numbers}, sort=Q, nonumberlist}

\newglossaryentry{vector-space}{name=\ensuremath{V},
  description={a vector space}, sort=V}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
A vector space \gls{vector-space} \ldots
\lipsum[1-10]

\glsaddallunused
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers did not work for me. All still produced an empty page when i used `\glsaddall \printglossary[title=Glossar, toctitle=Glossar]`
with the package `\usepackage[acronym, toc, section=section]{glossaries}`.

What did work however is `\usepackage[acronym, toc,section=chapter]{glossaries-extra}` with `\printunsrtglossary`

Comment: Can you please extend your answer to a full answer with complete example as shown in the other answers. Currently it is IMHO more or less only a comment to other answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).