# Using \glsaddall without listing page numbers

Tags: glossaries

In continuation to the [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133150/suppress-symbol-in-nomenclature-after-first-use/133164?noredirect=1#comment305894_133164)

How to use `\glsaddall` to list all the unused entries in list of nomenclatures and list of glossaries without printing the page numbers in the lists?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115635.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this one before, but did not rebuild the glossaries. It works.

Comment: So, can we close this one as a duplicate?

Comment: BTW, if you get unwanted commas in the glossaries, put `\glsaddallunused` just before `\end{document}`. Also you can remove `hyperfirst=false` if you don't need it...