# List of Symbols and Abbreviations with location

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, symbols, acronyms, big-list

I have a list of symbols and abbreviations. Please see my code below, at the end of this question.

This code works, but I would like to have my symbols/abbreviations with a LOCATION. By this I mean, to take one of the symbols in the text and mention it for the first time with the appropriate page in the document where it was used and so on...

```
\chapter*{List of Symbols}
\begin{abbrv}
\item[$\textbf{A}$]          a square matrix
\item[$\textbf{z}$]           a vector
\end{abbrv}
\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}

\begin{abbrv}
\item[CPU]                   Central Processing Unit
\item[NYC]                   The New York City
\end{abbrv}
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if I understand it correctly, you would like to reproduce the picture you've given? If so, have a look at the `glossaries` package, it can do everything you need.

Comment: @ riddleculous, yes, I would like to produce the list of symbols and abbreviations shown in the picture above.

Comment: The second example in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8951/78282) should describe exactly what you want, right? For your symbols use the "normal" glossary, for abbreviations, the acronyms.

Comment: @ riddleculous, thanks for your suggestions, but the example that you referenced uses the page numbers as well? Let's say, the abbreviation NYC I mentioned in my text, and now this should take automatically and put in the List of Abbreviations with an appropriate page number where it was used first?

Comment: exactly. Per default, the lists will list all occurences of the respective items, but if you add the package option `indexonlyfirst`, then only the first occurence is shown. If you have further questions, please try out the package and provied a MWE to clarify what you actually mean.

Comment: @ riddleculous, thanks a lot! I will try and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: @Sally7874 You might find [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254670) useful as well.